# Change text when clicking insert

Tags: html

I'm making a website to edit a special image faster, and I want to change the text from the `<text>` thing when clicking the button insert from the input type "creatorcode".

input type creatorcode and insert

```
<input type="text" id="entercolor" placeholder="Creator Code" onkeydown="submitOnEnter(event)" onfocus="clearWrongInput();" style="z-index:0;">
<button class="btn" type="button" style="z-index:0;" onclick="myFunction"();>Insert</button>
```

script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function myFunction() {
      document.getElementByTagName("text").innerHTML=document.getElementByTagName("text");
    }
  </script>
```

text

```
<b><text>creator-code</text></b>
```

anyone?

Comment: is there anyone that can help?

Comment: You have an extraneous `=` in your JS code. And also, there is no element with the ID of `text` or `text1` in your markup.

Comment: You have use wrong input type `creatorcode` you suppose to use type `text`.

Comment: I edited it, so now it shows what it is currently. still not changing the text of the <text>.

Comment: can you help me?

Comment: Hello, change `getElementById` to `getElementsByTagName("text")[0]` and change `.value` to `.innerHTML`. Also change `onclick="myFunction"` to `onclick="myFunction"();`

Comment: like this? document.getElementById('text').innerHTML=document.getElementByTagName("text");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few mistakes in code which were fixed in below code snippet. Try this I hope it'll help you out. Thanks

**Mistake 1 -** Change `input type="creatorcode"` to `input type="text"` there is no `creatorcode` input type in HTML.

**Mistake 2 -** Change `onclick="myFunction"` to `onclick="myFunction()"` you need to add `()` after your method name.

```js
function myFunction() {
    var code = document.getElementById('entercolor').value;
    document.getElementById("newCode").textContent = code;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="entercolor" placeholder="Creator Code" onkeydown="submitOnEnter(event)" onfocus="clearWrongInput();" style="z-index:0;">
<button class="btn" type="button" style="z-index:0;" onclick="myFunction()">Insert</button>
<b><text id="newCode">creator-code</text></b>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Link for jsfiddle:

```
<input type="text" id="entercolor" placeholder="Creator Code" style="z-index:0;">
<button class="btn" type="button" style="z-index:0;" name="insert_button">Insert</button>

<div>
Some text here...
</div>
</div>


 document.getElementsByName("insert_button")[0].onclick = function(){

    document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0].innerHTML = document.getElementById("entercolor").value
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/6drvcbz0/

Hope that helps.